# expose a private type for module extension in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, encapsulation, inclusion

I'd like to extend a module but I need access to its private components. Here's an example:

```
nat.mli:
type t 
val zero : t
val succ : t -> t

nat.ml:
type t = int
let zero = 0
let succ x = x + 1
```

I'd like to define a new module `Ext_nat` that defines a `double` function. I was trying to do something like this.

```
ext_nat.mli:
include (module type of Nat)
val double : t -> t

ext_nat.ml:
include Nat
let double x = 2 * x
```

It's not working as I don't have access to the representation of `x` in the last line.

Now that I'm thinking about this, it may not be such a good idea anyway    because this would break the encapsulation of `nat`. So what is the best way to do this? I could define a new module `nat_public` where `type t = int` in the signature, and define `nat` and `ext_nat` with a private `type t`.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `with type` statement. It is possible to write the code below in many different ways, but the idea is always the same.

```
module type NatSig =
  sig
    type t
    val zero : t
    val succ : t -> t
  end

module type ExtNatSig =
  sig
    include NatSig
    val double : t -> t
  end

module ExtNat : ExtNatSig =
  struct
    type t = int
    let zero = 0
    let succ = fun x -> x + 1
    let double = fun x -> x * 2
  end

module Nat = (ExtNat : NatSig with type t = ExtNat.t)

let z = Nat.zero
let _ = ExtNat.double z
```

The problem is that as far as I remember it's impossible to achieve this behavior with your file structure: you define your module implicitly with signature in .mli file and structure itself in .ml, so you don't have enough control over you module, that's why I  suggest you to reorganize your code a little bit (if it's not a problem).